# how to change the header style in a datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

anyone know a strait forward way to change the header for a spark datagrid in flex?  The chrome color stuff is not attractive at all, I just want to make something solid with a specified color.  I been at it for a long time, and reading various documents such as a SO that links to http://flex6packs.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/spark-datagrid-skinning-custom-column-header-colours/ but none seem to work out for me.  I'm using flex 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the header style of the spark datagrid you have to use headerrenderer.

following link provides a code sample for the same, and answers the question:

http://flex6packs.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/spark-datagrid-skinning-custom-column-header-colours/

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood correctly, the link I have left you an example of how to deal with "HeaderStyle"

[Link 1](http://flexponential.com/2011/10/30/changing-fontweight-of-spark-datagrid-headers/)

[Link 2](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/01/23/setting-the-column-header-text-color-on-a-datagrid-control-in-flex/)

For change the color background in the Style

```
 backgroundColor: yellow;
 backgroundAlpha: 1.0;
```

regars

Comment: This shows how to change the color of the font, but I want to change the header fill.  Not just the chrome color either, it looks terrible for certain colors.  I just want a solid fill color in the header

Comment: Se the background color of the component

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mxml part

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" width="60%" height="100%"
                         styleName="dataGrid">
```

Here is the css

```
.dataGrid
 {
header-colors:#f9f9f9, #ebebeb;
alternating-item-colors:#ffffff, #ebebeb;
roll-over-color:#eaeaea;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
font-size:13px;
color:#555555;
 }
```

Hope it will help.